# Altium: Grouping "Not Fitted" Components In Excel BOM

Tags: altium, bom

I would like to include "Not Fitted" components on my Excel BOM exported from Altium. This part is easy, all I need to do is check the "Include Not Fitted Components" box in the "Source Options" panel of the BOM configuration window. However, I would like to modify my Excel template to have a section specifically for "Not Fitted" components, with its own header, and have Altium automatically place the "Not Fitted" components in that section. What would I need to do in my Excel template to accomplish this?

In other words, I need to have Altium look at the "Fitted" column in the BOM and if it sees "Not Fitted" it needs to place these components in a separate section of the BOM (designated by the Excel template).

Comment: I doubt Altium is capable of doing that. A simple VB script can help you, but it's cumbersome solution.

Comment: In my experience Altium is extremely versatile and has lots of capabilities buried deep inside the tools and settings. I would be surprised if there *isn't* a relatively easy way to do this

Comment: @DerStrom8  What is wrong with the way Altium does it by default?  I can't think of a way to do what you're wanting, but also can't think of a need.  It groups them together at the end, with a specific "tag" to show they were Not Fitted.  Does this not meet your needs?  Just curious, sorry I don't have an answer.

Comment: @JoelWigton In the short term the default method may be sufficient but is not ideal due to the way our standard company BOM is set up. Before we had Altium we manually generated the BOMs and had a separate section for non-populated parts. The rest of the BOM is designed to include this section, and we are trying to keep this format (roughly, anyway) for consistency sake

Comment: I have not found an acceptable "Altium Way" of doing this. I've always just prefixed optional component values with an asterisk, which makes it easy to see/filter in the BOM. Works great but is a manual method.

Answer (score 0):

I found something for you:

http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Inclusion+of+Not+Fitted+Components+in+a+BOM

And you were right when you said in the comments that Altium is extremely versatile.

Comment: I already knew about this, and I mentioned it in my initial post. The problem is that I have a separate section at the end of my BOM that I want to use specifically for not-fitted components. Sure, it automatically groups them together at the end of the BOM but I want to have Altium send all of the components with the "Not Fitted" setting to a separate section of the BOM. The above link does not show how to do that.

Comment: I'm assuming that you need separate Excel sheets for fitted and not-fitted components. For that to happen, you can segregate them once you have them all in the excel.

Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Completely misunderstanding the question. The way the BOM is set up, the top section is normal and has all of the fitted components. At the end (bottom) of the BOM there is another section, much like the top section except it contains all of the *not fitted* components. I need Altium to determine where the break happens and populate only the top section with fitted and the bottom section with not fitted components

Comment: Okay. I understand now. First, you can select "fitted components" only and create your BoM, and then select "not fitted" components only and again create your BoM. I can't seem to find any other way to get Altium to do the job automatically.

Comment: And that's just it, I don't want to do it manually, it is extremely inconvenient to do it manually, so I am looking for a way to do it automatically

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding an addition parameter (named something like "special") on the target schematic symbol/s. Then in the OutJob open up the Reports Output and select the newly added parameter (it should now appear in the list) to allow the output BoM to include your new "special" column.

I just tried it and it works. Hopefully I understood your question; it's quit early in the day for me;)
[image: example1]
[image: example2]

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid you misunderstood. I am familiar with adding custom *columns* to the BOM. That's not the issue. In fact, most of the *columns* I put in my BOMs are custom. What I want to do is have custom *rows* at the bottom of my BOM listing the non-populated components (marked as "not fitted" in the variant). Basically I want one set of rows showing all my populated components (like normal), and then have a section break directly below that, and below the section break list all the rows for my non-populated components. Hopefully this clears it up

Comment: Copy that DerStrom8: On a similar note, I have seen an undesirable artifact in Altium that if I have more than one component of the same mfg p/n but (for one reason or another, usually a mistake on my part from coping parts around) the Descriptions and/or Comments are no longer identical the BoM outputs the components (even though they are still the same mfg p/n) on two separate line/row items on the BoM. Perhaps you can exploit this phenomenon to suit your needs. I am using AD15.1.16

Comment: that happens when you don't have the "Grouped Columns" set up correctly. I usually group using the Manufacturer PN and Notes (I put "DO NOT POPULATE" in the notes to get it on a separate line, but I cannot control where that line is placed). Once again this could easily be used to create a new *column*, but not a new set of *rows*. The closest I've gotten is what I mentioned before, where the "Not Fitted" components can be grouped together at the end of the BOM. This is great, I just want a page break with a label between the fitted and not fitted components